# Ranging [0,1] by different columns with R

Tags: r, range, normalization

I'm trying to normalize a table of people with different attributes (numeric, boolean...) with the [0,1] range, and I've tried this function:

```
ranging<-function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
```

But obviously it gets the min and the max from the whole table. I'm not used to R programming, how can I get the min and the max for each column, in order to normalize properly each column?

Comment: You can use `lapply(df1, min)` or `lapply(df1, max)` for each column min and max.  It is better to show a reproducible example and expected output

Comment: or `lapply(df1, ranging)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming that you are using a data.frame named df without any factor variables, the following code should work without any special packages (as suggested by @user20650:

```
ranging<-function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
dfNorm <- lapply(df, ranging)
```

If your data.frame has factor variables, which should not be normalized, you can use the following:

```
    dfNorm <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(is.factor(x), x, ranging(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If we are using `dplyr`, `mutate_each` can take the `ranging` function and apply to all the columns of the dataset.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
     mutate_each(funs(ranging))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v3 = c(0L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
v4 = c(1L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), v5 = c(2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), v6 = c(3L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), .Names = c("v3", 
"v4", "v5", "v6"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```